# Hide a button from another class

Tags: ios, swift

I want to adjust the visibility of the button in another class. I want the other classaki buttonnew to be active when the `fetchDeviesNewDevice()` function is called in the following code. 
I tried to do it, but it didn't work in the code below.

```
    class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate, MiniTabBarDelegate {

    @objc func fetchDeviesNewDevice(){
     let mainTableVC3 = DeviceTableViewCell()
                        mainTableVC3.newdevicechipnumber = self.newdevicechipnumber.text
                        mainTableVC3.buttonaktif()
    .... } }

    class DeviceTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
     @objc func buttonaktif(){
            buttonNew.isHidden = false 
 }
        lazy var buttonNew: UISwitch = {

            let sw = UISwitch()

            sw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            sw.isOn = false

            sw.isHidden = true

            sw.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleChangeStateNew), for: .valueChanged)
            sw.addTarget(self , action: #selector(didPressNew), for: .valueChanged)

            return sw
        }()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
 let mainTableVC3 = DeviceTableViewCell()
```

creates a new cell , you need to add the visibilty logic inside the model and reload the table

```
var hideBtn = false // default

@objc func fetchDeviesNewDevice(){

     hideBtn = true / false
     //reload the table / indexpath
}
```

Then inside `cellForRowAt` do

```
let cell = ////
cell.buttonNew.isHidden = hideBtn
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

in :

```
@objc func fetchDeviesNewDevice(){
        let mainTableVC3 = DeviceTableViewCell()
        mainTableVC3.newdevicechipnumber = self.newdevicechipnumber.text
        mainTableVC3.buttonaktif()
        ....

    }
```

instead of :

```
mainTableVC3.buttonaktif()
```

try :

```
mainTableVC3.buttonNew.isHidden = false
yourTableView.reloadData()
```

let me know if it worked

Comment: Are you sure fetchDeviesNewDevice() is being called?

Comment: Also you need to call tableView.reloadData() after you hiding the UIButton in order to refresh the cells